# Django model with 'order_with_respect_to': how to get object order?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models with an `order_with_respect_to` relationship:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    pass

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'book'
```

I know I can get the order of chapters like this:

```
my_book.get_chapter_order()
```

But I need the reverse operation: given a chapter, I want to know its position. I know there's a generated `_order` field, but it's suposed to be private, so I'd prefer not to use it.

My first approach would be something like this:

```
my_chapter = Chapter.objects.get(pk=WHATEVER)
chapters = my_book.get_chapter_order()

for position, chapter_id in enumerate(chapters):
    if chapter_id == my_chapter.id:
        break

print(position)
```

But it feels very dirty: I must get the whole order list each time I want to know a chapter's order. I think this should be just a chapter's property.

Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `index` method of the `list`type, like this:

`position = chapters.index(my_chapter.id)`